# Error in Big Query with wild card when performing SUM aggregation operation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to do a [SUM aggregation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#sum) using google big query on some data. I am trying to use [wild card](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference) to query over multiple tables. 
The [wild card](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference) format works for columns of some data types e.g. *INTEGER* but **fails** for others e.g. *FLOAT*. Following is a representation of queries I am trying to execute

> **[Update]** seems it fails for *trip_distance (FLOAT)* columns as of now. same query works fine for another column *passenger_count(INTEGER)*
>
> **FAILURE CASE : wildcard format for FLOAT (trip_distance)**
>
> query for single table:
>
> ```
> select sum(trip_distance)
> from  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_green_trips_*`
> where _TABLE_SUFFIX  in ('2014')
> ```
>
> query for multiple tables:
>
> ```
> select sum(trip_distance)
> from  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_green_trips_*`
> where _TABLE_SUFFIX  in ('2014', '2015')
> ```
>
> The above queries throw an error as below

**ERROR : Cannot read field 'trip_distance' of type FLOAT64 as NUMERIC**

[image]

I am not sure why the ABOVE error as the below queries **work** (I **want to avoid** the non wildcard one as it will become **huge** as one wants to query more tables) .

> **SUCCEEDS : wildcard format for passenger_count (INTEGER)**
>
> query for single table:
>
> ```
> select sum(passenger_count)
> from  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_green_trips_*`
> where _TABLE_SUFFIX  in ('2014')
> ```
>
> query for multiple tables:
>
> ```
> select sum(passenger_count)
> from  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_green_trips_*`
> where _TABLE_SUFFIX  in ('2014', '2015')
> ```
>
> **SUCCEEDS : normal syntax without wildcards**
>
> query for single table
>
> ```
> select sum(trip_distance)
> from  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_green_trips_2014`
> ```
>
> query for multiple tables:
>
> ```
> select sum(trip_distance)
> from 
> (
>   select trip_distance
>   from  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_green_trips_2014`
>   UNION ALL
>   select trip_distance
>   from  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_green_trips_2015`
> )
> ```

Can somebody advise what I am missing when I use the [wildcard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference). I prefer an answer which uses [standard sql format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/).

Comment: You should perhaps stop generating separate tables for each year.  Just have one table, with a date/integer column representing the particular year, and then aggregate based on that column.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have control over how tables are generated. I can only query them

Comment: OK, but does your second union query generate any errors?  It looks correct, at least from an ANSI standard point of view.

Comment: Second pair does work. Just want to avoid it as it becomes huge if I want to add in more tables

Comment: Well, your union query is probably your only option here, unless you can use dynamic SQL or a script to generate the query you want.  Use a single table in the future, if possible.

Comment: ok thanks Tim. DO you know of any reason why wildcard format does not work here

Comment: You _can't_ refer to table names using wildcards.  Such a feature, besides being a major security risk, also would be a pain to implement.

Comment: Thanks Tim but then what would be an acceptable use case for wildcard syntax provided by googl big query

Comment: Ok, for all intents and purposes, you _can't_ do what you are trying to do.  Use a union, or change your table structure.

Comment: Thanks, I get your point. The wildcard format does work for INTEGER columns though (see update)

Comment: @oldmonk . . . Please edit the question and show the error message.

Comment: @GordonLinoff screenshot added

Comment: @oldmonk - do you have this issue with your own data or you actually working with public data as in your question? please clarify. if you are working with your own data  - there is an easy workaround

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I am working with a public dataset so cant edit the table in anyway

Comment: Ok. I see. Just wanted to double check. so looks like legacy sql is the way for you, unless owner of dataset will fix the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I try to run this simple query:

```
select trip_distance
from `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_green_trips_*`
where _TABLE_SUFFIX  in ('2014')
limit 100
```

I am getting the error:

> **Query Failed**
>
> Error: Cannot read field 'trip_distance' of type FLOAT64 as NUMERIC

I have not seen this error before. The data looks okay in the preview pane. I can only assume that something has gotten messed up in the underlying data. In 2014 (assuming the data was loaded in that timeframe), the data type could not have been `NUMERIC` -- so I don't know where the `NUMERIC` comes from.

Needless to say -- given that the column cannot be read at all -- the column cannot be converted to any other type that I tried.

I think the data is broken. I'm not sure whom to contact at Google, but it should be fixed or removed.

EDIT:

I got it. The data is `NUMERIC` in the most recent version of the table (2018). The problem is the `*` syntax. This is using the most recent definition of the table, and there is a type incompatibility (it could do a conversion, but it doesn't).

I think you have figured out how to query each table independently, so you can work around this problem.

If this is a problem because you need to mix data from different years, then you can create a view which does the conversions you need (although using the view might increase the costs of your queries).

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That makes sense. I am currently using a legacy SQL query as a work around. Haven't been able to find a standard SQL way (other than the 2 mentioned above) to query multiple tables. Is there another way in standard SQL? Let me know if you know of a syntax different form above 2 and which works with standard SQL